# How to close modal programmatically in Bootstrap with React?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am using React, Bootstrap and jQuery all together. Don't ask me why, i know it's horrible, just don't have time to get rid of jQuery. I use Bootstrap v5 and I got a modal in there, js:

```
<div
  className='modal fade'
  id="exampleModal"
  aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div className="modal-content">
      <div className="modal-header">
        <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
          Select here
        </h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, I got the following as well, js:

```
<a
  className="nav-link wallet-btn"
  data-bs-toggle="modal"
  data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
>
  Connect here
</a>
```

and this `<a` just opens a modal which is great. Modal has a `x` button , js:

```
<button
  type="button"
  className="btn-close"
  data-bs-dismiss="modal"
  aria-label="Close"
></button>
```

and clicking on it just closes the modal.

**Problem** I need to be able to close the modal programatically. As you can see, bootstrap does all this with I think(not sure) - `data-bs-dismiss="modal"` , but now I need such thing programatically. I tried to `setAttribute` but didn't work.

Prefer to use direct js real quick somewhere that fixes it instead of another jQuery code.

Comment: Have you thought of looking at [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/)?

Comment: Just click the button via JS (jQuery or vanilla). jQuery: `$('.btn-close').click()`, vanilla: `document.querySelector('.btn-close').click()`

Comment: $("#exampleModal").modal("hide");

Comment: @BenCoffin wins :)

Answer (score 1):

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#methods

Show
`$('#myModal').modal('show')`

Hide
`$('#myModal').modal('hide')`